# How to modify variables from my __init__.py in other file?

Tags: python, variables, import, module, package

I am doing a project in python and I am trying to organize my code as well as possible. But I have a big problem. I created a __init__.py where I stored some variables. I would like to know how I can modify these variables in another python file by importing them, because it doesn't work.

Here is my tree:

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── thread.py
└── run.py
```

__init__.py:

```
dir1 = None
dir2 = None
len_dir1 = 0
len_dir2 = 0
sync_flag = "Synchronizing"
filter_flag = None
stop_flag = False
len_flag = 0
```

I want to modify the value of `dir1` for example, in my run.py:

run.py:

```
from app import dir1, dir2

def set_dir(grid_command):
    dir1 = grid_command[1]
    dir2 = grid_command[2]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Welcome to our Sync System:\n\nType \"HELP\" for more informations.\n")
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        set_dir(sys.argv)
```

I can't update this variable because when I print it, `dir1` = `None` (due to the initialization in the __init__.py)

Answer (score 2):

You are not updating `dir1` and `dir2` from the `app` module. What you are doing is creating `dir1` and `dir2` in your own module and updating those.

You meant to update the one in the `app` module:

```py
import app

def set_dir(grid_command):
    app.dir1 = grid_command[1]
    app.dir2 = grid_command[2]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Welcome to our Sync System:\n\nType \"HELP\" for more informations.\n")
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        set_dir(sys.argv)
```